# Streaming Video to YouTube (API)

Tags: c#, php, .net, youtube, video-streaming

I've been given the job of developing a website where registered users can register, and then using their webcam on our site stream live video *to* our youtube account, via our website.

But finding information on this has proven quite difficult, and I'm beginning to think the worst; It's not currently possible.

I did find *one* Google result that mentioned this streaming technology but upon clicking the link found absolutely no relevent information whatsoever. Does anybody know if this can be done? Where the API would be and and links/resources would be extremely helpful and appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see how this was off-topic. It's programming-related.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? I am interested in one that lets you feed a stream live to youtube, preferrably in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am no expert in this area but what if the stream is stored on your server first and then uploaded to youTube as a normal video file? I believe Red5 offers a plugin which you can use to allow people to record video from their webcam. A quick google search gives me this http://www.red5-recorder.com/ .. check it out, it might be useful for your purpose.

Comment: I take it YouTube does not offer this type of streaming yet? That sounds interesting, atm I am open to any ideas, so long as we can achieve what they wanted, I guess it doesn't really matter how we go about it as long as it works. Thanks for the link, checkin' it out now.

Comment: yes as far as i know youtube doesn't allow anything like that but then again i am not an avid youtube user .. hope red5 helps you solve what you are trying to do.

Comment: This does not solve the case of live-streaming. Any ideas for that?